# Angular 5 - routing with wildcard

Tags: angular, router

I try to define a specific route in my module, but I don't know how to manage that :

```
http://myserver.com/prefix-randomname/mycomponent
```

`randomname` is a real random name with random chars, generated for only one session. I only know the `prefix`. But I want to open a route leading to `mycomponent`.

Last but not least, I cannot remove `prefix-randomname` in the url, because the server will not work without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if it will work for you, but you can change the `baseUrl` at app initialisation using the [`APP_BASE_HREF`](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) constant.

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

export function appBaseFactory(appInitService: AppInitializationService): () => string {
    return (): string => `/${location.pathname.split('/')[1]}`
}

@NgModule({
  // ...,
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: appBaseFactory}]
])
export class AppModule {}
```

I believe this will keep your router happy

If the `appBaseFactory` doesn't work, you might want to change it to immediately return the `location.pathname` stuff, instead of returning a `Function`